# excel vlookup multiple values and workbooks

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I know this topic has been asked about before but nothing quite covers what I need. So here's the thing..

I have two workbooks. One is exported from another program which shows a staff member's Surname, first name, email and which ward they work on.

[Workbook1 example]

[image]

The second is the full staff list which has the same details but also a check list column.

[Workbook2 example]

[image]

What I need is a macro (probably a vlookup) which takes the information from the workbook1, checks against surname, first name and ward on workbook2 to ensure that it is the correct member of staff, copies the email onto workbook 2 and also fills the checklist column on workbook 2 to "Yes".

I'm afraid I am at a loss as to how to incorporate all of this together. Please help.

This is what I have so far but my knowledge is limited and did not know how to proceed.

```
Private Sub UpdateTraining_Click()

Dim I As Integer
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim CopyData As String
Dim RwCnt As Long
Dim RwCnt2 As Long
Dim Rw As Long
Dim Clm As Long
Dim SName As String
Dim FName As String
Dim Wrd As String
Dim vArr
Dim ClmLet As String

Set Ws1 = Workbooks("Nursing Docs Training Record.xlsm").Worksheets("Staff Training Record")
Set Ws2 = Workbooks("Nursing Docs Training Record.xlsm").Worksheets("Do Not Use")

Workbooks.Open ("C:\TypeformNursingDocumentation.xlsx")
Set Ws3 = Workbooks("TypeformNursingDocumentation.xlsx").Worksheets("tWeXNp")

RwCnt = Ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
RwCnt2 = Ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Rw = Ws3.Range("F2").Row
Clm = Ws3.Range("F2").Column

Table1 = Ws3.Range("F2:F" & RwCnt)

vArr = Split(Cells(1, Clm).Address(True, False), "$")
ClmLet = vArr(0)

For Each cl In Table1
    Ws3.Range(ClmLet & Rw).Select

    SName = ActiveCell.Value
    FName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Wrd = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value    
    Rw = Rw + 1

Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of your worksheets?

Comment: This is not so hard to achieve but you should show something you have tried. At least share your sample workbook with us.

Comment: I have updated my question with my code so far and pictures of the example workbooks that I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with formulas but then you have to open `Workbook1` for the formulas to work in `Workbook2`. So below approach uses VBA to achieve the results

Copy the below UDF in a module in **`Workbook2`**:

```
Sub UpdateMyList()
    Dim oSourceWB As Workbook
    Dim oSourceR As Variant
    Dim iTotSRows&, iTotCRows&, iCC&, iSC&
    Dim oCurR As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' First lets get source data
    Set oSourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\EmpLookup.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)    ' Change the source file name

    With oSourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")                                         ' Change the source sheet name
        iTotSRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        oSourceR = .Range("A2:G" & iTotSRows)
    End With
    oSourceWB.Close False

    ' We now need the data from the sheet in this workbook to compare against
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8")                                      ' Change the sheet name to the sheet in your workbook
        iTotCRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        oCurR = .Range("A2:H" & iTotCRows)
    End With

    ' Next, lets compare and update fields
    For iCC = 1 To UBound(oCurR)
        For iSC = 1 To UBound(oSourceR)
            If (oCurR(iCC, 1) = oSourceR(iSC, 6)) And (oCurR(iCC, 2) = oSourceR(iSC, 5)) And (oCurR(iCC, 5) = oSourceR(iSC, 2)) Then
                oCurR(iCC, 7) = oSourceR(iSC, 7)
                oCurR(iCC, 8) = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Finally, lets update the sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A2:H" & iTotCRows) = oCurR

End Sub
```

I've commented on the lines where you need to change references to workbook or worksheets. As long as you have updated the workbook and worksheet references, this should give you the desired results

> I built the above UDF based on the columns as you provided in your question. If the columns change, you will have to modify the UDF or get the columns dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use and If(Countif()) style function, where the countif checks for the presence of your value, and the if will return true if it is a match, then you can use the if true / false values accordingly. Let me know if you need more details but it could look something like this =IF(COUNTIF(The selected cell is in the selected range),"Yes", "No"). Then record this as a macro and copy the code into yours.